Close dropdown menu or change element behaviour when click outside the element with reacrjs
I have ul and th li tags rendred from api data I want to hide ul when I click outside it
I use useEffect with ref.current.contains(event.target) todo that with window.addEventListener("mousedown",fn) this fn use to setStatus to false to close or hide ul but when I click  any li reactjs treat it as outside ul so I cannot make any action on this li element
How can I fix this ?
I tried to use event.stopPropagation() but it did not work

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
